Flow or lightning web component?
I need to build a flow and I don't know if it is plausible and I should use a lwc. My screen flow should do the following:

Screen 1: Show records of LoB (object A), each with a checkbox to be selected.

Screen 2: Show different Families (field b) from object Product2 (object B), grouped by the LoB (object A) that have been selected, and they are part of. Each Family (field b) should have a checkbox to select it.

Screen 3: Show all the Product2 records that have one of the Families from the previous screen as a field. All the products should be listed and have a checkbox, and also there should be a checkbox to select all from one family.

Screen 4: Summary with a list of all products selected grouped by family.

After finishing records of object C will be created with the information of the products selected (object C has a lookup to Product2 that will be filled with the records of the previous screen).


I hope I made it clear to understand.
Thanks for your help.

I think Flow might be complex to build rather than implementing it in LWC. Also LWC allows for a more visually appealing and user-friendly interface for this multi-step selection process, and LWC component can still leverage Flow functionality in the background.

It is again based on your current scenario and how your system is build. Also you need to think future perspective, if the requirement will go complex and those complex things can be handled by flow. go for it. Or as previous commnent if your end user's visual apealing is more important go for LWC.

My main concern is how to show all the records of screens 2,3 and 4, how to group them and be able to select all the checkboxes of a certain group. Thanks for your help.
